# How to use default.ctp in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I just finished the "15 min Blog Post tutorial" included in the documentation for cakephp. I was asked for another tutorial to change the layout for first tutorial.

However, I am fairly new to MVC programming/Cakephp and I have no real clue how to do so. Well, I know I need "default.ctp" placed in app/views/layouts/    and I presume I need to include 
 to include my data? . . .

I am really at a loss of what to do. I set up my default.ctp as I mentioned above, but when I go to localhost:9999/posts the layout is still the same. I guess I need to include a stylesheet (and if so, where?)

I guess if someone can point me in the right direction to a beginner's guide to layout styling or how to use it I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Your question gets to some very very basic fundamentals of Cake.  Your layout is mostly for structure; $content_for_layout is the variable that gets set with the contents of the view, and is then placed in the layout.  Your default layout (if you don't create one) is inserted from the cake libs; once you add one to views/layouts/default.ctp, that one will be used rather than the library layout default.  If you're struggling with this stuff, you really need to look at the book more.

Comment: Please select one answer to mark you question as answered!

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to read the following from the cookbook: [Layouts](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1080/Layouts) and [CSS](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1437/css). Then copy the layout from `/cake/libs/view/layouts/` to `/app/views/layouts/` and modify it to your needs. After that create you stylesheet (or modify existing one) in `/app/webroot/css/` and include it in your layout.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create in app/View/Layout a file named "**my_posts_layout.ctp**"
2. In your PostController set $this->layout = '**my_posts_layout**';

This way you should view the content defined on my_posts_layout.ctp.

Comment: CakePHP 2.6.0, put this line to the end of specific method (in controller class): `$this->render('my_posts_layout');`

Answer (score 1):

Lack of stylesheets has no impact here.

How MVC works in CakePHP:

- The router dispatches an incoming request to an appropriate Contoller.
- The appropriate Controller function executes (no output, just fetching data, setting up variables).
- The appropriate view is rendered. In fact, the output of the view is just contained in $content_for_layout.
- What you really get back in the browser is in the layout. Therefore you can put your view's output into the layout by `echo $content_for_layout` in default.ctp. (Of course you can also have different layouts.) In addition, the layout can be enhanced with elements.

Comment: Thanks guys. I got it working fairly quickly. As it turns out, Coda was set to hide extensions, so when I saved the file as default.ctp, it automatically was trying to save it as default.ctp.ctp (which I have had this issue before, and Coda likes to reset this on me).

@Travis Leleu, Thanks! Yeah, I have been rereading the book quite frequently. I thank I might just switch to another editor for my cakephp usage to avoid these issues in the future.

Comment: Try Eclipse PDT http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/setting-up-eclipse-to-work-with-cake

Answer (score 0):

I really recomend the CakePHP CookBook, easily found from the CakePHP homepage. Modifying default.ctp should edit your applications layout.

A more specific question (eg. code samples of your default.ctp, expected results etc) might help people provide a better answer than mine.

Comment: Ah yes, I am sorry. Well I take it you are familiar with the 15 min blog post tutorial. I was asked to complete the said tutorial as well as create categories for theabove mentioned tutorial, which leaves me with localhost:9999/posts as well as localhost:9999/ categories (all with their own controllers, views, etc).. SO in the cookbook, I found where they were talking about how to use the layout structure by adding <?php echo $content_for_layout ?> to default.ctp . However, it doesnt seem to change anything.. DO you know how to add styling to this?

Comment: You will need to edit the default CSS file. Inside the 'webroot' directory i beilve, at least i think it was last time i used CakePHP (quite a while)...